# Having issues displaying modal view programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am very very new to iOS programming / Objective C.

The flow of events I want to have happen is: user selects tab from tab bar view controller. Once VIEW A has been loaded it will open a modal window to get some information

### VIEW A - (void)viewDidLoad

```
ModalYearPickerViewController *modalYearPickerViewController= [[ModalYearPickerViewController alloc] init];

[self presentViewController:modalYearPickerViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

I am trying to have my year picker view load up right away so the user can select a year from my picker (in VIEW B), then close the modal window after the value has been passed back to VIEW A.

Now, the fist view loads, then goes to a black screen automatically. I am unsure why as my view controller for modalYearPickerViewController has a picker etc on it.

Any tips or help loading a modal view controller programmatically would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: to test something, add this line before calling present: modalYearPickerViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];, does it change the black view to red? also try moving to viewDidAppear

Comment: Yes the view turns red, it also does the same thing in viewDidAppear

Comment: so then the problem would be that your modal year picker view controller isnt configured properly, show how you set it up and someone might be able to help work out why the picker isnt displayed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using storyboards :

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [self storyboard];
```

This will return the storyboard of your current view controller. I am assuming your View Controller A is also on your storyboard.

```
ModalYearPickerViewController *modalYearPickerViewController  = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ModalYearPickerViewController"];
```

This will instantiate your view controller from the storyboard. But one other thing you have to do is set your view controllers storyboard id to `ModalYearPickerViewController`. You can set this right below where you set your custom view controller class in the storyboard.

```
[self presentViewController:modalYearPickerViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

and done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a xib file for that viewContrioller, it has to be loaded as well, to do that you have to call:

```
ModalYearPickerViewController *modalYearPickerViewController = 
[[ModalYearPickerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModalYearPickerViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: I am using storyboards and there is no .xib for this scene

Comment: If you are using a storyboard, why are you presenting the VC programmatically?

Comment: Its a VC I only want to show under certain circumstances. I want my user to select a year using the picker in the view I want to load up. After they have selected their year I want to goto the normal VC.

Edit: As I mentioned, i am VERY new to this. If I should be using a segue then so be it. I figured i was onto something with this direction but maybe not...

Comment: ok you have 2 options here, either give that modal VC an identifier then load it using **instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:** or create a segue from the presenting VC to the modal and give it an identifier and call it yourself when needed using **performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:**